# Why is my regex not working in ruby but elsewhere

Tags: regex, ruby

so, I'm trying to get the follow regex to work in ruby, it appears to almost be doing what i want in a regex editor im using, but when I try it in ruby it returns no match? Could use a little help on this one as im really new to regex.

my regex is the following:

```
string.match(/XIGSharedData(.*?});/)
```

and basically what im trying to do is get the following:

```
"XIGSharedData\",[],{\"raw\":\"{\\\"config\\\": ... about 5000 more characters.... };
```

Im trying to grab from the "{" before "raw" to its matching closing "}", which i have almost working in a regex editor, (im still capturing from "XIGSharedData" onwards in the regex editor, and it says its terminating at the right spot farther down, but in ruby it says it captures nothing? do I need to do something else for this regex in ruby to get it to detect a match?

Any help is much appreciated. Currently working in a very old codebase and trying not to have to re-write everything since were deprecating the whole codebase in like two months.

Comment: Your example string does not have a semicolon (;) in the end, is that a typo or is it actually so? Your regex is expecting one.

Comment: yes sorry, i should have included that. So i found if i added an "m" to the end of the regex, it works in my ruby console. So now I just have to figure how to start capturing at "{" before raw.

Comment: @Ilovebathroomlights Adding `/m` to the regex makes it multi-line, i.e. the `.*` will also match newline characters. However, the example code given in your StackOverflow question does not include a newline character - so we would have had little chance in guessing this as a solution! Please take care to provide a *reproducible* example of your problem.

Comment: Additionally, it *looks like* what you actually have a data structure here (CSV, probably??) -- Have you considered parsing it as such (e.g. `CSV.parse`) instead of relying on a fuzzy text-matching regex? Your regex approach would be far less performant, and potentially flawed - e.g. what happens if the "about 5000 more characters" also contains a `}` character somewhere in the middle?

Comment: *"it appears to almost be doing what i want in a regex editor im using"* -- Presumably because the unspecified regex editor (which it would have been helpful if you told us which one!) has multi-line regex mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to grab from the "{" before "raw" to its matching closing "}"

Would I be correct in thinking you are attempting to parse the contents of a <script> tag from HTML scraped from Instagram? If so and as @tom-lord suggested, you ought to use the appropriate tools in preference to a regexp. I was able to parse the text you are after from a similar looking js data structure as follows:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rkelly' # gem rkelly-remix

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/Cfee9XNubCg/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet' #an example which has script tag containing "XIGSharedData\",[],{\"raw\..
html = URI.parse(url).open.read
doc = Nokogiri::HTML html
js_tag_text = doc.xpath("//script[contains(text(), 'XIGSharedData')]").text

ast = RKelly::Parser.new.parse js_tag_text

node_index = nil
ast.each_with_index do |node, i|
  node_index = i if node.value == '"XIGSharedData"'
end

node_text = nil
ast.each_with_index do |node, i|
  node_text = node.to_ecma if i == node_index + 3 # gets the node element from {\"raw\"..
end

puts node_text
=> {
   "raw": "{\"config\":...
   ...}
   } # matching closing '}'
```